# SQLAlchemy: SQL Expression with multiple where conditions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having difficulties writing what should be a simple SQL update statement in SQLAlchemy Core.  However, I can't find any documentation, examples or tutorials that show how to combine multiple where conditions.  I'm sure it's there - just can't find it.

Here's the table:

```
self.struct    = Table('struct',
                     metadata,
                     Column('schema_name',         String(40),  nullable=False,
                                                                primary_key=True),
                     Column('struct_name',         String(40),  nullable=False,
                                                                primary_key=True),
                     Column('field_type',          String(10),  nullable=True),
                     Column('field_len',           Integer,     nullable=True) )
```

Here's the insert & update statement:

```
def struct_put(self, **kv):
   try:
       i = self.struct.insert()
       result = i.execute(**kv)
   except exc.IntegrityError:   # row already exists - update it:
       u = self.struct.update().\
           where((self.struct.c.struct_name==kv['struct_name']
                  and self.struct.c.schema_name==kv['schema_name'])).\
           values(field_len=kv['field_len'],
                  field_type=kv['field_type'])
       result = u.execute()
```

The code handles the insert fine, but updates all rows in the table.  Can you help me understand the syntax of this where clause?   All suggestions are welcome - thanks in advance.

EDIT:  The corrected clause looks like this:

```
        where((and_(self.struct.c.parent_struct_name==kv['parent_struct_name'],
                    self.struct.c.struct_name==kv['struct_name'],
                    self.struct.c.schema_name==kv['schema_name']))).\
```

It's a very simple syntax, but given the many layers of SQLAlchemy it was surprisingly difficult to determine what exactly applied within this context.

Comment: A shortcut to using and_() is to chain together multiple where() clauses. So: .where(a==1).where(b==2).where(c==3). See [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions).

Comment: This might also help: `from sqlalchemy import and_`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using the Python "and" operation, which will evaluate to a only one of the clauses surrounding it. You should try using the "and_" function from SQLAlchemy instead. Put those two clauses inside the "and_" function.

Comment: Ah, I figured the answer had to be that simple.  I couldn't find any examples of this in the tutorial or anywhere else.   Functions were described, but it wasn't clear to me that this was where I would use them.   Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_

just adding link of an example for `and_` in where clause query.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `&` *python operator*.

For example:

```
query.where(
   (ModelName.c.column_name == "column_value") &
   (ModelName.c.column_name == "column_value)
)
```

For example, if you had a query like this

```
user_query = User.select().where(
   (User.c.id == 12) &
   (User.c.email == "myemail@gmail.com")
)
```

This will generate a raw SQL like this

```
select * from users where id = 12 and email = "myemail@gmail.com"
```

Comment: I'm using `.where()` without `&` and everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLAlchemy, `tablename.c` is a special value that you use when constructing conditions that will be treated by SQLAlchemy at runtime.

In this particular case, you're simply saying "update all the rows where the column named `struct_name` matches the value passed in to `struct_put(struct_name="struct_value", schema_name="schema_value")`, and the column named `schema_name` matches the value passed in as `schema_name`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#the-where-clause), [`Select.where()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.where) also accepts multiple conditions as `*whereclause` with default `AND` behavior:

```
stmt = (
    select(Table)
    .where(
        Table.firstname == "John",
        Table.lastname == "Smith"
    )
)
```

Comment: This does appear to work, and is similar to how the .filter statement worked. Thank you. This seems like the answer with the cleanest and easiest to remember syntax